# Java Return result of JOOQ query

Tags: java, mysql, database, jooq

I have a question. Someone recently told me to use JOOQ if I interact with databases, so I have been reforming my code to work properly with JOOQ, but I am struggling with the way, how I select data from the database and return it. I have the following `SqlConn` class:

```
package com.company.database;

import org.jooq.DSLContext;
import org.jooq.Result;
import org.jooq.Record;
import org.jooq.SQLDialect;
import org.jooq.impl.DSL;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class SqlConn {

    private final String SERVER = "database.me:3306";
    private final String DATABASE = "testdb";
    private final String USERNAME = "test";
    private final String PASSWORD = "test";
    private final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://" + SERVER + "/" + DATABASE;
    

    public HashMap<String, String> getMarketCoins() {
        
        HashMap<String, String> returnValue = new HashMap<>();
        
        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD)) {
            DSLContext create = DSL.using(conn, SQLDialect.MYSQL);
            Result<Record> result = create.select().from("MarketCoins").fetch();

            for (Record r : result) {
                returnValue.put(r.getValue("Market").toString(), r.getValue("Coin").toString());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

Now this code works like it should, but this is just a function that collects data from 1 specific table. My previous code was build that I could provide a Query and the code would execute the query and return the result, but with the new JOOQ method, it seems that I need to create a function for each different query and table. I watched this beginner tutorial about JOOQ: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4H3AGK_hNMA, but in this video he also creates multiple functions for different database calls. Is this correct, or is there a better way to easily get data from my database, where it doesn't matter for which table? I have a lot of tables in my database, so that would mean that I need a lot of function writing :(

Please let me know!

Comment: How did you do it before jOOQ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As recommended in the [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4H3AGK_hNMA) you've linked, jOOQ is best used using the [code generator](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/). Your particular query can be implemented like this:

```java
public Map<String, String> getMarketCoins() {
    return
    create().select(MARKET_COINS.MARKET, MARKET_COINS.COIN)
            .from(MARKET_COINS)
            .fetchMap(MARKET_COINS.MARKET, MARKET_COINS.COIN);
}
```

A few remarks:

1. `MARKET_COINS` is a generated class for your table by the same name. It contains type safe column information, such as `MARKET_COINS.MARKET`, of type `Field<String>`. Hence, the `String` type is already available to you. You don't have to do anything
2. I'm assuming you're going to use a connection pool (e.g [hikari](https://www.baeldung.com/hikaricp)) and inject a `DSLContext` instance to your class (e.g. using Spring). You can still use `DriverManager`, but usually, you're better off with a connection pool. That is irrelevant to your jOOQ usage, though
3. Always specify explicit column lists in your `SELECT` clauses, never `SELECT *` if you're not going to process the extra columns.
4. jOOQ has a useful [`ResultQuery.fetchMap()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/ResultQuery.html#fetchMap(org.jooq.Field,org.jooq.Field)) method, so you don't have to loop your results manually
5. jOOQ is all about [dynamic SQL](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dynamic-sql/). It should be simple to write queries in a way that you don't have to repeat these pattern, e.g. if you frequently have to fetch keys and values from a table:

```java
public <R extends Record, K, V> Map<K, V> getKeyValue(
    TableField<R, K> key, TableField<R, V> value
) {
    return
    create().select(key, value)
            .from(key.getTable())
            .fetchMap(key, value);
}
```

Now, call this e.g. using:

```java
Map<String, String> result = getKeyValue(MARKET_COINS.MARKET, MARKET_COINS.COIN);
```

This obviously greatly profits from the [code generator](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4H3AGK_hNMA) usage, again.

Comment: Okay thank you, but this means that when I want to do a `SELECT` on a table named `Orders`, I need to create a new function for that?

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk:  You don't need to. You can put everything in a 65839 line long method. jOOQ won't judge you.

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk: I'm sorry for the snarky reply yesterday :) I understand that this seems all quite complex when you're starting out with these things. This particular question about where to implement SQL logic isn't strictly about jOOQ (or even JDBC). It's an architecture question: *"Where do I implement **any** kind of logic"*, and there are no obvious answers to that. With jOOQ, you can refactor common SQL logic very easily, because jOOQ makes dynamic SQL easy. But is that really a requirement for you? Hard to say.

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk: If you have to write 50 distinct queries, then you have to write 50 distinct queries. There's nothing wrong with that. People have done this for ages. Mostly, they've "hidden" their SQL queries in some layer, which they call things like "DAO" (Data Access Object) or "Repository" or "Service" or whatever. Each method on these wrapper object types represents one or several queries. As you go on, there will be some common patterns, which you can refactor as I've shown.